# Angular.js $setValidity onLoad Page

Tags: java, angularjs, formulário, jsp

- Cenário:

  Possuo um formulário com 3 etapas, uma jsp para cada etapa. Em uma determinada jsp existe um *input* `text` com a diretiva `ng-minlength` e um `onChange` que chama uma função que valida com o `$setValidity` caso o valor informado seja inválido.
- Problema:

  Quando a campo é inválido e ocorre a navegação entre as etapas, ao voltar pra etapa o campo perde o status de inválido. Como solução, eu tentei validar o campo ao carregar a pagina mas ocorre erro ao executar o código a baixo pois o formulário ainda não foi carregado:

  `$scope.form.numeroCartao.$setValidity("valid", true);`
- Pergunta:

  Como validar um campo com o `$setValidity` ao carregar a página?

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de setar o valor do campo usando o **value** do input, carregue o valor no **ng-model**.

Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
<input type="text" ng-minlenth="10" ng-model="teste" value="${ vdo.teste }"/>
```

Faça isso:

```
<form ng-init="teste = '${ vdo.teste }';">
...
<input type="text" ng-minlenth="10" ng-model="teste"/>
```

Outra... não escute o evento nativo **onChange** do elemento, com Angular o ideal é usar a diretiva **on-change**, ou então criar um **$watch** no seu controller.

Comment: Olá Victor, passei a chamar minha função no ng-init direto no form, mas ele ainda não consegue localizar o name do form que eu quero invalidar conforme o codigo: `$scope.form.numeroCartao.$setValidity("valid", false);`.

Comment: `TypeError: Não é possível obter a propriedade 'numeroCartao' de referência indefinida ou nula`

Comment: O numero do cartão ainda não foi carregado, dentro do formulário.

Comment: Cara, coloca o teu HTML em um Gist ou um JSFiddle pra gente ter uma idéia melhor do que você está fazendo.